# Ext.data.jSonP Sencha API with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I am trying to get a JSon from my server. I am calling the API like this:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
        url: 'http://dev.mysite.com/temp.cfm',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        timeout: 40000,
        params: {
            format: 'json'
        },
        success: function(result, request) {
            // Get the weather data from the json object result
            var weather = result; console.log('Succ');
        },
        failure: function(result, request) {
            // Get the weather data from the json object result
            var weather = result; console.log('Fail');
        },
        callback: function(result, request) {
            // Get the weather data from the json object result
            var weather = result; console.log('CallB');
        }
    });
```

I am using Coldfusion as Serverside. So, I am simply doing this:

```
<cfreturn '#url.callback#({\"LOGINSTATUS\":\"fail\"})'>
```

That returns the following string:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.callback1({\"LOGINSTATUS\":\"fail\"})
```

But my request always times out.

Comment: its defined by the internal mechanism when the jsonp request is made. all your server side needs to return is that callback key wrapped json string

Comment: @DmitryB With a little more debugging I just came to know that my request is getting Timed out. Any idea what could be the reason?
I also tried setting Timeout: '40000', but it still times out.

Comment: how much time does it spend on the server? Check to make sure you return the callback key on the server side exactly as supplied to you from the client.

Comment: Does the CF server respond to any other commands you make directly? What happens when you hit the JSON URL directly instead of through Sencha?

Comment: @Sharondio When I hit directly it returns this: "Ext.data.JsonP.callback1( {\"LOGINSTATUS\":\"fail\",\"RESPONSEMESSAGE\":\"Check your Username or Password\"} )"

Comment: @DmitryB I've set the timout of the request to be 60 seconds. It takes all the fifty seconds and then gives me timeout error. Yes I am sure about the callback key. That's same.

Comment: I dont think it should return "Ext.data.JsonP" part, just the callback

Comment: In URL it's sending **callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback01**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what was the actual problem. I just tried using cfm file instead of cfc on server side and everything started working.

If anyone could explain why this happened I'll accept that explanation as correct answer.

Thanks DmitryB and Sharondio for you time and trying to help me fix it. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: That is the first mention of using a .cfc. Might want to include the non-working cfc code in your original question. Maybe someone will spot the problem.